# Theories Clarification

Tags: magnetic-field, geology

I attended a seminar and the presenter was discussing various theories to explain the strong magnetic anomalies on Mars as spotted from orbit. One theory was that the "Lithology is rich in magnetic minerals" whilst another was that the "there is a large volume of magnetic minerals", I would appreciate if anyone could explain the difference as I seem to think they resemble the same thing

Comment: "Rich" would probably mean the magnetic minerals are mixed in with the rock, and "large volume" would probably mean there are concentrations of magnetic rock

Comment: If you can include any information about the origin of the theories,( papers, citations, author names etc.) that would be very helpful, but in this case that might be difficult since you are just quoting what you'd seen in seminar.